# Unir dos inner join con full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Es posible unir dos inner join con un full outer join? Tengo este join

```
select h.No_Serie, DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura) as Mes, DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura) as Año, sum(c.Saldo_Pagado) as Ingreso
from Historico_Pagos_Rentas h inner join cxc c on h.Id_Sucursal=c.Id_Sucursal and h.Id_CxC=c.Id_Consecutivo
where h.Id_Sucursal='cordoba' and h.Estatus='a' and c.Estatus='a' and h.Referencia<>'' and h.No_Serie<>'' and c.Saldo_Deuda=0 and c.Monto_Deuda=Saldo_Pagado
and h.Pago_Total=c.Monto_Deuda
group by h.Referencia, h.No_Serie, DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura), DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura)
order by No_Serie, DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura), DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura)
```

que me trae los ingresos agrupados por serie, mes y año, como en la siguiente tabla:

```
No_Serie            Mes     Año     Ingreso
ZELPBJFK50008PV     12      2018    1044
ZELPBJFK50008PV     1       2019    1044
ZELPBJFK50008PV     2       2019    1044
ZELPBJFK50008PV     3       2019    1044
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     10      2018    2400
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     11      2018    3217.99
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     12      2018    2582.8
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     1       2019    2528.77
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     2       2019    2632.1
```

Después tengo este otro join

```
select ir.No_serie, DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion) as Mes, DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion) as Año, sum(ds.Costo*ds.Cantidad) as Gastos from Informa_Rentas ir inner join Servicios s
on ir.No_Serie=s.No_Serie and ir.Id_Sucursal=s.Id_Sucursal inner join DetalleServicios ds
on ds.Servicio_FK=s.Id_Servicio and ds.Id_Sucursal=s.Id_Sucursal inner join servicios_rellenados sr
on sr.Id_Sucursal=s.Id_Sucursal and sr.Id_Servicio=s.Id_Servicio
where ir.Estatus='A' and ds.Estatus='A' and s.Estatus<>'B' 
group by DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion), DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion), ir.No_serie
order by No_Serie, Año, Mes
```

que me trae los gastos, igualmente agrupados por serie, mes y año, de esta forma:

```
No_serie            Mes     Año     Gasto
ZELPBJFK50008PV     11      2018    3865.81
ZELPBJFK50008PV     1       2019    82.32
ZELPBJFK50008PV     3       2019    82.32
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     10      2018    3865.81
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     11      2018    82.32
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     12      2018    246.96
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     1       2019    246.96
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     2       2019    82.32
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     3       2019    82.32
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     4       2019    164.64
```

Estoy buscando si hay alguna forma de unir ambos join, creo que con un full outer join, de tal forma que el resultado sea algo como esto:

```
Serie               Mes     Año     Ingreso     Gasto       Total
ZELPBJFK50008PV     11      2018                3865.81     -3865.81
ZELPBJFK50008PV     12      2018    1044                    1044
ZELPBJFK50008PV     1       2019    1044        82.32       961.68
ZELPBJFK50008PV     2       2019    1044                    1044
ZELPBJFK50008PV     3       2019    1044        82.32       961.68
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     10      2018    2400        3865.81     -1465.81
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     11      2018    3217.99     82.32       3135.67
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     12      2018    2582.8      246.96      2335.84
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     1       2019    2528.77     246.96      2281.81
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     2       2019    2632.1      82.32       2549.78
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     3       2019                82.32       -82.32
ZELPBJFK50000AJ     4       2019                164.64      -164.64
```

Supongo que se debería hacer con un 'full outer join' porque si las combino con inner join me borras las filas que no aparecen en alguno de los dos lados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es convertir ambas consultas en CTEs (common-table-expression). Así las puedes manejar como si fueran dos vistas. Para esto, le quité el ORDER BY que no tiene sentido (y por lo mismo no está permitido) dentro de vistas o CTEs.

```
WITH cteIngresos AS(
    SELECT h.No_Serie, 
            DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura) as Mes, 
            DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura) as Año, 
            sum(c.Saldo_Pagado) as Ingreso
    FROM Historico_Pagos_Rentas h 
    INNER JOIN cxc c on h.Id_Sucursal = c.Id_Sucursal AND h.Id_CxC = c.Id_Consecutivo
    WHERE h.Id_Sucursal = 'cordoba' 
    AND h.Estatus = 'a' 
    AND c.Estatus = 'a' 
    AND h.Referencia <> '' 
    AND h.No_Serie <> '' 
    AND c.Saldo_Deuda = 0 
    AND c.Monto_Deuda = Saldo_Pagado
    AND h.Pago_Total = c.Monto_Deuda --Esta condición podría ir en el JOIN por cuestiones de agrupación de lógica.
    GROUP BY h.Referencia, --Este podría omitirse de aquí porque no está siendo mostrado.
             h.No_Serie, 
             DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura), 
             DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura)
    --order by No_Serie, DATEPART(YEAR, h.FLectura), DATEPART(MONTH, h.FLectura)
),
cteGastos AS(
    SELECT ir.No_serie, 
            DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion) as Mes, 
            DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion) as Año, 
            sum(ds.Costo*ds.Cantidad) as Gastos 
    FROM Informa_Rentas ir 
    INNER JOIN Servicios s ON ir.No_Serie = s.No_Serie AND ir.Id_Sucursal = s.Id_Sucursal 
    INNER JOIN DetalleServicios ds ON ds.Servicio_FK = s.Id_Servicio AND ds.Id_Sucursal = s.Id_Sucursal 
    INNER JOIN servicios_rellenados sr ON sr.Id_Sucursal = s.Id_Sucursal AND sr.Id_Servicio = s.Id_Servicio
    WHERE ir.Estatus = 'A' 
    AND ds.Estatus = 'A' 
    AND s.Estatus <> 'B' 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, sr.F_Realizacion), 
             DATEPART(YEAR, sr.F_Realizacion), 
             ir.No_serie

)
SELECT ISNULL( i.No_Serie, g.No_Serie) AS No_Serie,
       ISNULL( i.Año, g.Año) AS Año,
       ISNULL( i.Mes, g.Mes) AS Mes,
       ISNULL( i.Ingreso, 0) AS Ingreso,
       ISNULL( g.Gastos, 0) AS Gasto,
       ISNULL( i.Ingreso, 0) - ISNULL( g.Gastos, 0) AS Total
FROM cteIngresos i
FULL JOIN cteGastos g ON i.No_Serie = g.No_Serie
                     AND i.Año      = g.Año
                     AND i.Mes      = g.Mes
ORDER BY No_Serie, 
         Año, 
         Mes;
```